# Sdf created is getting deleted after code first migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

I am working on code first migration with SQL Server compact edition in a WPF application.

I am able to generate the `.SDF` database file using code-first and can apply the migrations but in of the user machine the `.SDF` is getting created (only empty `.SDF`, no tables added) but migrations are not applied and after a few seconds it is getting deleted. Only a few users are facing this problem(we are using click once deployment)

I have created a sample application to generate the `.SDF` database file using code first to the user but in that application also it is the same behavior. I kept the logs as well but we didn't get any exceptions.

Below is the code I am using for applying migrations.

```
var connectionString = Constants.SqlCEConnectionString;
var providerName = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0";

var configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(connectionString, providerName);
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);

IEnumerable<string> migrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations();

if (migrations != null && migrations.Count() > 0)
{
    migrator.Update();
}
```

The `.SDF` should not be deleted and migrations should apply

Comment: The `.sdf` file is typically a **SQL Server Compact Edition** database file - not SQLite....

Comment: Ok I have updated Do you know the problem here

Comment: are you sure this is the code that is responsible? Its hard to imagine the migrator randomly deletes the database in some cases.

Comment: I have no idea whether migrator deleting or something deleting. I have observed this issue with a particular user. For all other users it is working fine

Comment: Could you please share the connection string?

Comment: it will build dynamically and below is the connection string example 

"Data Source="C:\Users\<user-machine-name>\AppData\Roaming\Test\Test.sdf";Mode=Read Write;Persist Security Info=True;"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the user has roaming enabled? I would consider using:

```
 "Data Source="C:\Users\<user-machine-name>\AppData\Test\Test.sdf;"
```